# Induction proof: $n^2+3n$ is even for every integer

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction

> Prove using simple induction that $n^2+3n$ is even for each integer $n\ge 1$

I have made $P(n)=n^2+3n$ as the equation.

Checked for $n=1$ and got $P(1)=4$, so it proves that $P(1)$ is even.

Then I do it with random integer $k\ge 1$ and assume for P(k).

My issue is that I am not sure how to do $P(k+1)$, which is what I eventually need to prove the main equation.

Comment: Just as a comment... Proof without induction - $n^2+3n=n(n+3)$ and one of the terms has to be even.

Comment: What are we allowed to use about parity ?

Answer (score 2):

$$P(k+1)=(k+1)^2+3(k+1)=k^2+2k+1+3k+3$$
Now can you express $P(k+1)$ in terms of $P(k)$? And once you've done that, what conclusion can you draw on $P(k+1)$, using the assumption that $P(k)$ is even?

Comment: shouldnt 3(k+1) be 3k + 3?

Comment: yes it should `:) `

Answer (score 1):

$$P(k+1)=(k+1)^2+3(n +1)=\color{red}{k^2}+2k+1+\color{red}{3k}+3=\color{red}{P(k)}+2k+4$$

Comment: In what does this prove that $P(k+1)$ is even ?

Comment: I got to that as well. But I am not sure what it means. Shouldnt the "2k+4" be 1 in order for it to be a proof?

Comment: P(k) is even and 2k+4 is even...

Comment: @SAR note that $2k+4$ is even for all $k$. So if $P(k)$ is even, as is the induction hypothesis, then so is $P(k)+2k+4$, which is $P(k+1)$. If the $2k+4$ were a 1, it would be odd, and we could not conclude.

Comment: I'd consider using an `align*` rather than the `gather*` you seem to have chosen, @ajotatxe.

Comment: How do you know that $2k+4$ is even ?

Comment: @Yves it is the sum of two even numbers, namely $2k$ and 4. Alternately, $2k+4=2(k+2)$.

Comment: @MickG: I know about that (obviously!). But one may wonder if such an argument is acceptable because it could be used to prove $n^2+3n$ even as well. Pure induction would be preferable.

Answer (score 1):

$$P(1)=4,$$ which we assume is known to be even.
$$P(n+1)=(n+1)^2+3(n+1)=n^2+3n+2n+4=P(n)+2n+4.$$

Then, assuming that we can take for granted that $m$ and $m+2$ have the same parity,

$$P(n),P(n)+2,P(n)+4$$
and by induction
$$P(n)+2n+4$$ are all even and so is $P(n+1)$.

Then by induction, all $P(n)$ are even.

Comment: Why the absurd downvote ?

Comment: Don't know who gave that. Yours is correct

Answer (score 0):

I got it now. P(k+1)= P(k)+2k+4 can only give even values and hence it is proven P(n) can only have even answers.

Thank you everyone for the quick responses!